# Java Duplicate local variable error

Tags: java, duplicates

I have a problem in java that I cannot fix, I looked this error up, but nothing was like mine. I tried using the quick fix in eclipse but it only gave me more errors.
The error is on line 53
Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AA extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton Button;
    private JTextField TextField;

    public AA() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Backup         ");
        add(label);

        label = new JLabel("Save name");
        add(label);

        TextField = new JTextField(15);
        add(TextField);

        Button = new JButton("Backup");
        add(Button);

        label = new JLabel("Restore         ");
        add(label);

        label = new JLabel("Backup name");
        add(label);

        TextField = new JTextField(15);
        add(TextField);

        Button = new JButton("Restore");
        add(Button);

        event e = new event();
        Button.addActionListener(e);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        AA gui = new AA();

        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(1360, 600);
        gui.setTitle("Save Backup 2");
        event gui = new event();

    }

    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Done");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which is line 53, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes, please tell us the error message and show the line.

Comment: [Can you see it now?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/frolZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables called `gui`. Rename one of them

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    AA gui = new AA(); // <-- one

    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setSize(1360, 600);
    gui.setTitle("Save Backup 2");
    event gui = new event(); // <-- two

}
```

Change

`event gui = new event();`

to

`AA.event guiEvent = gui.new event()`.

This would associate the inner `event` instance with an enclosing instance of `AA` (`gui`).

Comment: Then It says Multiple markers at this line
 - No enclosing instance of type AA is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type 
  AA (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of AA).
 - The value of the local variable gui1 is not used

Comment: `event` is an non-staic inner class. Therefore it should be created with an enclosing instance - `gui.new event()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
AA gui = new AA();
```

This declares a variable named `gui`.

```
event gui = new event();
```

And in the same scope (the same method) you declare another variable also named `gui`. Rename of these two.

As a side note, just renaming one of them won't be the end of your problems. The second variable (let's call it `gui2`) should be created like this:

```
event gui2 = gui.new event();
```

This is because `event` is a non-static nested class, and it needs a reference to the containing class.